# Using UNION withing ORDER in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to retrieve latest records of two tables using `UNION`, it returns data, but not latest records, even with `ORDER BY`. It's my query:

```
    SELECT TOP(1) OwnerID,NewsTitle,NewsCreationDate,NewsTitle,NewsEnglishName 
FROM TheaterNews 
    UNION
    SELECT TOP(3) OwnerID,NewsTitle,NewsCreationDate,NewsTitle,NewsEnglishName  
FROM MoviesNews
    ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

This is query's output:
[image: output using UNION]

But the latest record of `TheaterNews` is newer:

```
SELECT  OwnerID,NewsTitle,NewsCreationDate,NewsTitle,NewsEnglishName 
FROM TheaterNews 
ORDER BY NewsCreationDate DESC
```

[image: latest records for TheaterNews table]

How can I fix this? even with another method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work in your instance. Might be a rough solution but you will get your answers. you can replace the #tables with @tables.

```
SELECT TOP(1) 
    OwnerID,
    NewsTitle,
    NewsCreationDate,
    NewsEnglishName 
into
    #Table1
FROM 
    TheaterNews 
ORDER BY 3 DESC

SELECT TOP(3) 
    OwnerID,
    NewsTitle,
    NewsCreationDate,
    NewsEnglishName
into
    #Table2
FROM 
    MoviesNews
ORDER BY 3 DESC

select * from #Table1
union
select * from #Table2

drop table #Table1
drop table #Table2
```

Comment: `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.`

Comment: I forgot to remove the union between the first two selects. I have edited the source. Copy it from above and try it again...

Answer (score 7):

The `order by` applies to the entire result of the union, not the separate queries, so the `top` is applied before the result is sorted.

Use subqueries to order the separate results:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT TOP(1) OwnerID,NewsTitle,NewsCreationDate,NewsTitle,NewsEnglishName
  FROM TheaterNews
  ORDER BY 3 DESC
) x
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT TOP(3) OwnerID,NewsTitle,NewsCreationDate,NewsTitle,NewsEnglishName
  FROM MoviesNews
  ORDER BY 3 DESC
) y
```

Answer (score 3):

Because top clause is getting executed before order by clause. try this

```
  Select * from (SELECT TOP(1) OwnerID,NewsTitle,NewsCreationDate,       
                    NewsEnglishName 
                 FROM TheaterNews      ORDER BY 3 DESC) as tn
  UNION
  Select * From (SELECT TOP(3)       
                 OwnerID,NewsTitle,NewsCreationDate,NewsEnglishName  
                 FROM MoviesNews     ORDER BY 3 DESC) as mn
  ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

The outer order by will order the union result

Comment: I got this error: `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.`

Comment: I got another error message: `Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The column 'NewsTitle' was specified multiple times for 'tn'.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The column 'NewsTitle' was specified multiple times for 'mn'.`

Comment: Query given in question also have multiple NewsTitle cols. I have removed the duplicate. Try now

Comment: NewsTitle was repeated in the query - that is obvious

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select * From ( SELECT TOP(1) OwnerID,NewsTitle,NewsCreationDate,NewsTitle,NewsEnglishName 
    FROM TheaterNews ORDER BY NewsCreationDate DESC) as tempA
        UNION
     Select * From  ( SELECT TOP(3) OwnerID,NewsTitle,NewsCreationDate,NewsTitle,NewsEnglishName  
    FROM MoviesNews ORDER BY NewsCreationDate DESC) as tempB
```

Comment: This is not valid MS-SQL syntax. You will get: `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.`

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'` means you can't amend it by adding aliases like that.

Comment: And when you say, "Try this:", you should already have been the first to do so. :)